# How to remove or set help content to the Help menu available in WizardDialog in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am calling `WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog` and a new window is opening with a help icon in the bottom button tray in extreme left corner. I don't need that button.
How to remove that or is there any way to add help content to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bug 330206](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330206):

> To hide the "`?`" you need to call `setHelpAvailable(false)` on your `WizardDialog`.
>   If you don't control/create the dialog, you can add the following method to
>   your wizard:

```
public void setContainer(IWizardContainer wizardContainer) {
    super.setContainer(wizardContainer);
    if (getContainer() instanceof TrayDialog)
        ((TrayDialog)getContainer()).setHelpAvailable(false);

}
```

---

To add Help, you can see the general idea in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg13942.html), but take into account [bug 3827](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3827):

> if you are opening the wizard in a `WizardDialog` you create, you have to set help on the dialog's shell: ex.

```
dialog.create();
WorkbenchHelp.setHelp(dialog.getShell(), new Object[]{IHelpContextIds.NEW_WIZARD});
dialog.open();
```